# ValueError when assigning m2m relationship after data saved - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Music'

Tags: python, django, object, model, m2m

I'm creating an object 'Show' with many attributes. One of its attributes is 'categories' which is a Many to Many field, related to another object 'Categories'.

Before I create the 'Show' (by taking data from a passed in object), I'm creating the categories for which that Show will be assigned, like this:

```
for each_category in parsed_podcast.categories:
        Category.objects.get_or_create(title=each_category,
                                        slug=slugify(each_category),
                                        full=each_category,
                                        )
```

The above code is creating objects in my Category model, I can check and see that they are there. Once they are there, next I create the Show object, with lots of attributes which I've stripped because they're not relevant:

```
try:
        podcast_instance = Show.objects.get(title=parsed_podcast.title)
except Show.DoesNotExist:
        podcast_instance = Show(title=parsed_podcast.title,
                    slug=slugify(parsed_podcast.title),
                    image_title=parsed_podcast.image_title,
                    image_url=parsed_podcast.image_url,
                    .....
                    )
       podcast_instance.save()
```

All of this is working fine, until I now try to assign the category (from parsed_podcast.categories) to the newly created Category created in the first step, like so:

```
for each_category in parsed_podcast.categories:
            print('The category in the parsed podcast is {}'.format(each_category))
            podcast_instance.categories.add(each_category)
```

I can never assign the category - it always just remains as an option when I check the Django Admin on the model. I want to assign it programmatically but I get I get back an error saying:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Music'
```

Tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "podcasts.py", line 211, in <module>
    podcast_s()
  File "populate.py", line 205, in podcast_scrape
    submit(parsed_podcast,podcast_rss)
  File "populate.py", line 118, in submit2
    podcast_instance.categories.add(each_category)

  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 926, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1073, in _add_items
    '%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 59, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "C:\Users\p\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Music'
```

I have a feeling that whats in my parsed_podcast.categories isn't always the same. Is there an effective method to clean this data up each time? Or is there another problem.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't pass the string there. You need the Category instance that you created in the first step. I'm not sure why you have separate loops - why can't you do it all in one step? I think you need to show how these three snippets fit together; show the full code in context.

Comment: My friend, relax. While maybe you are used to these things, the OP is new and is trying to understand how this can be done as he doesn't know well how to work with many to many.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a string, which you parsed, when you should either pass the `pk` or a `category` object.

When you are creating the `categories`, use the object created.

```
for each_category in parsed_podcast.categories:
       category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title=each_category,
                                        slug=slugify(each_category),
                                        full=each_category,
                                        )
       print('The category in the parsed podcast is {}'.format(each_category))
       podcast_instance.categories.add(category)
```

Comment: Hey thanks - so this worked. I'm not entirely sure I understand how. Where you have 'category, created' I don't fully understand what this is doing...

So the first variable 'category' is the actual object? And the second is a bool to see if it really created the object or not...

Comment: But I've not worked much with tuple unpacking like that yet - I'm quite new. So that's a tuple unpack, and I'm getting back category object, created True or False, then in that for loop assigning the newly created category to the Show.

Maybe I do get it.

Thanks.